# Merging arrays from multiple MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to write some query that will take documents about YouTubers and their videos, and then return a single list of all their videos in chronological order.

So far with my query (in Mongoose):

```
return mongoose.model('creators').find({
  id: {}
})
```

I get these results:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b0891a3dcec4912601e32ce",
        "name": "CaptainDisillusion",
        "id": "UCEOXxzW2vU0P-0THehuIIeg",
        "videos": [
            {
                "_id": "5b0891a3dcec4912601e32cf",
                "name": "Quick D: A Fighter Jet Says Hi",
                "id": "-NPmBkYb_mY",
                "date": "2018-05-10T16:30:30.000Z"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b08967b66d8321034176afb",
        "name": "Curious Droid",
        "id": "UC726J5A0LLFRxQ0SZqr2mYQ",
        "videos": [
            {
                "_id": "5b0891a3dcec4912601e32cf",
                "name": "Guest post bloggers wanted for the Curious Droid website",
                "id": "sNLvdoValBw",
                "date": "2018-05-23T16:30:30.000Z"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Ideally what I'd like to do is return something along the lines of:

```
"videos": [
            {
                "_id": "5b0891a3dcec4912601e32cf",
                "name": "Guest post bloggers wanted for the Curious Droid website",
                "id": "sNLvdoValBw",
                "date": "2018-05-23T16:30:30.000Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5b0891a3dcec4912601e32cf",
                "name": "Quick D: A Fighter Jet Says Hi",
                "id": "-NPmBkYb_mY",
                "date": "2018-05-10T16:30:30.000Z"
            }
        ]
```

Returning just the one array of all the documents combined and in newest-first order.

Is that possible to do and if so how do I accomplish it?

Thanks!

Comment: If all you want your queries to return is "just" the data from within embedded arrays, then simply "don't embed it in the first place". The idea of "embedding" data is when your access pattern wants both the parent and the detail within a single request without overhead. If you just want these separate all the time, then separate the collections. Anything that "just gets the array items" out of this is **causing more overhead** than the embedding seeks to avoid, Change the data structure if this is how you want to use it.

Comment: Hi Neil, I completely agree with you. But this is just one way I want the data to be used, it certainly would be an advantage in this case to not have them embedded, but there are reasons for them to be embedded also.

Comment: If `videos` array contains multiple video then how the output look like? Show all of them?

Comment: Yeah, show all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `aggregate()` instead. Either using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) where you have it:

```
return mongoose.model('creators').aggregate([
  // { "$match": { ... } },                      // A real condition to match the document
  { "$unwind": "$videos" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$videoes" } }
])
```

Or using [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with all fields explicitly:

```
return mongoose.model('creators').aggregate([
  // { "$match": { ... } },                      // A real condition to match the document
  { "$unwind": "$videos" },
  { "$project": {
     "_id": "$videos._id",
     "name": "$videos.name",
     "id": "$videos.id",
     "date": "$videos.date"
  }}
])
```

Those are the only things that promote the embedded array content to the "top level" of the document in output.

**NOTE**: Any query conditions on either the document or array content should be done **"before"** the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). This means applying the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) valid for query conditions and possibly applying a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) projection on the array content first. If you don't do those "first" you are creating unnecessary overhead for your application.

The whole process of using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is really quite expensive anyway. It would be far wiser to actually take a good look at your query patterns and really make a decision if it is in fact worth keeping the documents embedded or if your queries are indeed more frequently suited to placing the documents in a separate collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$unwind` to flat the array items, then promote inner `$videos` as new root item along with `$sort` to order your videos item.

```
db.tests.aggregate([
      {$match: ...},
      {$unwind: "$videos"}, 
      {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$videos"}}, 
      {$sort: {date: -1}} // Newest first
])
```